# .getText() not retrieving the text message from div class tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

From the following HTML code

```
<div class="message-main-contents">
  <div class="message-title">Title Message</div>
  <div class="message-content">
    <div class="licenseexpiryannouncement">
        <div>
            Message Content 1
            <a class="licenseexpiryannouncement-installlicenselink">Link that can be clicked</a>
            under Home> Upload.
        </div>
        <div>Message Content 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to retrieve the "Title Message" text using the following code but is returning empty string

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[contains(@class, 'message-title')]")
private WebElement contentMessageTitle;

String titleMessage = contentMessageTitle.getText();
System.out.println(titleMessage);
```

Comment: How do you know you have the right element? Have you tried your XPath in the browser dev console to verify that it's the only one (or at least first) on the page that satisfies the locator?

Comment: @JeffC IMO, Even being the first match won't be working across all browsers and versions. Locators `xpath` or `css` needs to be unique. :) Thanks

Comment: @JeffC I tested the XPATH in the browser dev console to verify that only that particular element is returning.

Comment: @DebanjanB Sure it does. I use it all the time. Sometimes you can't get a unique locator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also encountered this sometimes in my code that the getText() method do not return you with the text and instead return an empty string. I have found a workaround for this by reading the attribute value **"textContent"**.

you can read the text using a workaround

```
String titleMessage = contentMessageTitle.getAttribute("textContent");
```

This way you can read the content of the **'contentMessageTitle'** locator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[@class='message-title']")
private WebElement contentMessageTitle;

String titleMessage = contentMessageTitle.getText();
System.out.println(titleMessage);
```

> or

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[@class='message-main-contents']/div[@class='message-title']")
private WebElement contentMessageTitle;

String titleMessage = contentMessageTitle.getText();
System.out.println(titleMessage);
```

> or

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[@class='message-main-contents']/div[@class='message-title']")
private WebElement contentMessageTitle;

String titleMessage = contentMessageTitle.getAttribute("text");
System.out.println(titleMessage);
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.